# Getting foreign key from RelationshipEndMembers in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-relationship, t4

I'm trying to automate some EF6 linq queries with some T4 templates.

I have a main table called Application that has many 1-* and a couple *-* relationships.

I've been able to figure out how to get to the foreign key table Id values for simple navigation properties but I'm having issues with the many to many relationships.

Here's the code I've been able to figure out so far.

```
var association = ((AssociationType)entity.RelationshipType);

        if (association.ReferentialConstraints.Count > 0)
        {
            var fromProperties = association.ReferentialConstraints[0].FromProperties;
            var toProperties = association.ReferentialConstraints[0].ToProperties;
        #>
        //query = query.Where(p => p.<#=toProperties[0].Name#> == idToFind);
        <#
        }
        else if (association.RelationshipEndMembers.Count > 0)
        {
            var test = (AssociationEndMember)entity.FromEndMember;
            // ????????
// Trying to create something like
// query = query.Where(p => p.ManyToManey.ForeignKeyId== idToFind)
// I'm able to find the ManyToMany value but not the foreign Key value
            #>
                var hellowordl = "True";
            <#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I ended up going through the edmx properties and searching for the primary key of the tables

```
var allEdmx = typeMapper.GetItemsToGenerate<EntityType>(itemCollection);

// entity is just an entry in allEdmx    
    var association = ((AssociationType)entity.RelationshipType);

    if (association.ReferentialConstraints.Count > 0)
    {
        var fromProperties = association.ReferentialConstraints[0].FromProperties;
        var toProperties = association.ReferentialConstraints[0].ToProperties;
    #>
    //query = query.Where(p => p.<#=toProperties[0].Name#> == idToFind);
    <#
    }
    else if (association.RelationshipEndMembers.Count > 0)
    {


var getPriamryKey = allEdmx.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == entity.FromEndMember.Name);
            var simpleProperties = typeMapper.GetSimpleProperties(getPriamryKey);
            if (simpleProperties.Any())
            {
                var primaryKeys = typeMapper.GetPrimaryKeys(ef, simpleProperties);

                if (primaryKeys.Any() && primaryKeys.Count() == 1)
                {
#>
        //query = query.Where(p => p.<#=entity.Name#>.<#=codeStringGenerator.JustGetName(primaryKeys.FirstOrDefault())#> == idToFind);
        <#
                }
}


// Added this to the codeStringGenerator class
    public string JustGetName(EdmProperty edmProperty)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0}",
            _code.Escape(edmProperty)
            );
}
```